# Find out where UNIX daemon gets stuck?

Tags: c, debugging, unix, gdb, daemon

Years ago, I wrote a UNIX daemon (`wsqueryd`) that puts itself in the
background:

```c
pid_t pid;

pid = fork();
if (pid < 0)
  misc_log_error_and_exit("Could not fork parent process");

if (pid > 0) // => this is the parent process
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); // terminates it

// Creates an new session for the process.
if (setsid() < 0)
  misc_log_error_and_exit("Cannot create new session");
```

Now, I realize that sometimes the daemon gets stuck. I attached `gdb`:

```sh
$ cd $DAEMON_SRC_PATH
$ ps aux | grep wsqueryd
apache   20735  [...]
$ sudo gdb wsqueryd # daemon runs as different user
[...]
(gdb) attach 20735
Attaching to program: [...]/wsqueryd, process 20735
warning: .dynamic section for "/lib/libk5crypto.so.3" is not at the expected address (wrong library or version mismatch?)
warning: .dynamic section for "/lib/libkrb5support.so.0" is not at the expected address (wrong library or version mismatch?)
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/libcurl.so.4.2.0.debug...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libev.so.4...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/libev.so.4.0.0.debug...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libev.so.4
Reading symbols from /lib/libz.so.1...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib/libz.so.1.2.5.debug...done.
done.
[...]
(gdb) list
1       // (C) [...]
2
3       #include <stdlib.h>
4       #include <stdio.h>
5       #include "daemon.h"
6       #include "misc.h"
7       #include "retrieval.h"
8
9       int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
10        misc_init(argv[0]); // to be called at the very beginning
```

How do I find out *where* the daemon gets stuck? (with surrounding code, and with the ability to step through it)

Comment: The gdb command `bt` might be a good place to start. It shows the backtrace of wherever you're currently stopped at.

Comment: `bt` seems to show the correct location. But that's not helpful for investigation. I want to see surrounding code, and I want to step through it. The problem: When I run `list`, I only see the beginning of `main.c`, as shown above.

Comment: `bt` would show you were thr process got stuck. How would you expect to be able to trace if the process is stuck?

Comment: `bt` can show you the line where the daemon is waiting, but without the source code you won't be able to browser the "surroundings" of the stuck function.

Comment: I'm sure you already know the command "list" will list around where you currently are... but did you know the command "up" will take up up the stack one level, changing the context of where "list" displays from, giving you access to variables from that scope, etc.? Also the command "down" does the reverse.

Comment: @mah `backtrace` plus `up` a couple of times does the trick. I still wonder: Why does `list` initially show the wrong position (the very beginning of the program)?